# How to delete zero elements in a 3D matrix?

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy

I have two arrays `input` and `label`. Each array has size `3x2x2x2`, that indicate `3` elements of `2x2x2` matrix. The array `label` have some 
elements (`=2` in my bellow code) has zero value. I want to delete/remove them to the `label` array. I also want to delete elements in the array `input` that the corresponds to the deleted index in the the `label` array. How can I do it in python? Thanks

```
import numpy as np
input=np.arange(3*2*2*2).reshape(3,2,2,2)
label=np.arange(3*2*2*2).reshape(3,2,2,2)
# Assign value
label[0]=0
label[2]=0   
print input
print label
#Delete element 
for i in range(label.shape[0]):
    if(np.sum(label[i])==0):
        print i
        #del label[i, :, :, :]
#Expected result: non-zero element are label[1] and input[1]
```

Comment: I don't think the numpy array is the best kind of data structure for your purpose.  The `numpy.ndarray` object is modeled on the "array" in the sense of uniformly typed and sized objects stored in a memory block for random access, rather than arbitrary insertion or deletion.  What you can do is to maintain separate indices for the "special" locations and skip them in later use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach with masking -

```
mask = ~(label == 0).all(axis=(1,2,3)) # or (label != 0).any(axis=(1,2,3))
new_label = label[mask]
new_input = input[mask]
```

I am outputting these `label[mask]` and `input[mask]` as new output arrays, just to show/indicate that these arrays be new arrays and not views into the input arrays. Strictly speaking deleting elements off an array is not possible, but reassign. So, we can do the reassigning part, like so -

```
label = label[mask]
input = input[mask]
```

---

Another way with finding those indices along the first axis and then using `np.delete` -

```
idx = np.flatnonzero((label == 0).all((1,2,3)))
new_label = np.delete(label, idx, axis=0)
new_input = np.delete(input, idx, axis=0)
```

Again, we are not actually deleting elements, but just creating new copies, which could be reassigned as discussed before.

Comment: Perfect solution. What is `all(1,2,3)`?

Comment: And why don't you use the `label = label[mask]`, instead of `new_label`. Is not safety?

Comment: Great. I voted it as my solution. Just an extended question. If my label is `label=np.arange(2*3*4*2*2*2).reshape(2,3,4,2,2,2)`. And I also want to delete the zero element as above. How could I obtain the mask equation? Thanks

Comment: @user3051460 Edit `.all(axis=(1,2,3)) ` to `.all(axis=(1,2,3,4,5))` basically taking all axes but the first one.

Comment: Sorry for reply late. I think I did not give you full information. When I create `label=np.arange(2*3*4*2*2*2).reshape(2,3,4,2,2,2)`, it means create `2x2x2` patches. I want to delete the patches`2x2x2` which has whole values are zero.  The `.all(axis=(1,2,3,4,5))` may not work in that case. I guess it is `mask = ~(label == 0).all((3,4,5))`. Hence the full code may be `input=np.arange(2*3*4*2*2*2).reshape(2,3,4,2,2,2)
label=np.arange(2*3*4*2*2*2).reshape(2,3,4,2,2,2)
label[0,0,0]=0
label[0,0,1]=0
mask = ~(label == 0).all((3,4,5))
label = label[mask]
inout = input[mask]`. Is it right?

Comment: @user3051460 Yup, that's it!

Comment: But I got the inconsistent shape between original label and new label. The shape of label before delete is 2x3x4x2x2x2 but the shape of label after delete is 22x2x2x2.

Comment: @user3051460 Well you can't delete patches and still maintain the multi-dimensional formatted data.

Comment: So it auto reshape to me to new dimensional instead of just remove patches in the array and reduce the dimension like `1x2x4x2x2x2`, instead of `2x3x4x2x2x2` (just assump delete two patches)